# How can I show one record's associated records in another table in CRUD?

Tags: playframework, crud

Take the tutorial YABE as example, in the CRUD, for Post, it can show its related tags, but it can not show its related comments. So how can I let it show its related comments ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Limitation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/crud#limitation)
>
> The CRUD module only shows bi-directional relationships in one of the
>   two entities: the one that does not have the mappedBy attribute.

Use the custom tag if you need to.
Something like:

```
<div id="crudListTable">
    #{crud.table fields:['name','description','comments']}
    #{crud.custom 'description'}
       #{if object.description}${object.description.length() > 50 ? object.description[0..50] + '…' : object.description}#{/if}
    #{/crud.custom}
    #{crud.custom 'comments'}
        #{list items:object.comments, as:'comment'}
            ${comment.description} /
        #{/list}
    #{/crud.custom}
    #{/crud.table}
</div>
```